# How to work with nested Maps in JAVA efficiently?

Tags: java, python, dictionary, hashmap

In Python one can easily do:

```
if dictionary[objA][objB][objC][objD] == None:
    dictionary[objA][objB][objC][objD] = objE
```

But in Java one needs to have a null check at every level. Is there any efficient way to convert the python code to Java code.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a null check at every level in Python also?

Comment: Using multi dimensional arrays will not require null checks, but yeah, it's not a map.

Comment: This data structure seems absurd.  You wouldn't use a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>>` in practice.  You'd make your own separate object to encapsulate that kind of thing.

Comment: As @Makoto said, this is highly unidiomatic Java. If I *had* to work with a data structure of this sort (e.g., some sort of generic JSON manipulation), I'd be using Groovy and the `?.` operator.

Comment: @chrylis:  If this were JSON I'd be using Gson.  Or something at least sensible to deal with a data structure like that. ;)